# search all columns of listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

Good day.

Could someone tell me how I search through all the columns of a listview?
At the moment I have a code that only searches the first column (with index 0).

```vb
Dim ItemsList As New List(Of ListViewItem)
```

After filling the listview:

```vb
ItemsList.AddRange(ListView1.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem))
```

Well, the selection (search) of values ​​by the text field itself:

```vb
    Private Sub TxtSearchLog_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim showitems As New List(Of ListViewItem)
        For Each i As ListViewItem In ItemsList
            If i.Text.ToLower.Contains(TxtSearchLog.Text.ToLower.Trim) Then
                showitems.Add(i)
            End If
        Next
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        ListView1.Items.AddRange(showitems.ToArray)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private allItems As New List(Of ListViewItem)

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop()

    Dim searchText = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
    Dim items = allItems.Where(Function(lvi) lvi.SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem).Any(Function(lvsi) lvsi.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1)).ToArray()

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(items)
End Sub
```

Firstly, you should not filter on the `TextChanged` event itself. If the user wants to search for a string of ten characters, your code would filter ten times when all but the last were useless. Instead, you should use a `Timer` with a fairly short `Interval` that you start/restart each time the `Text` changes and then only filter when the `Timer` `Ticks`. That way, you won't be filtering multiple times while the user is typing. You can experiment to get the best `Interval` value so that the user doesn't have to wait too long for the filter to happen but also doesn't have to type really quickly to avoid spurious filters.

As for the actual filtering, this code uses LINQ to do that. The `Where` function is what does the filtering, just like a `WHERE` clause in SQL. In this case, the result includes only those items that match the condition specified in the `Where` call. That condition is that the `Text` of any subitem contains the specified search text. Note that I have actually used a proper case-insensitive comparison, rather than using the hack of changing the case of the text. That hack will generally work and, I think, will always work in English but there are some cases in some languages where it won't work, so it is generally discouraged.

Unfortunately, the .NET Framework version of `String.Contains` cannot do case-insensitive comparisons, so you have to use `IndexOf` instead. If you're targeting .NET Core (including .NET 5.0 or later) then you do have an overload of `Contains` that will take a `StringComparison` argument.

For the record, if you wanted to modify your existing code as little as possible then you could just change this:

```vb
If i.Text.ToLower.Contains(TxtSearchLog.Text.ToLower.Trim) Then
```

to this:

```vb
If i.SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem).Any(Function(lvsi) lvsi.Text.ToLower.Contains(TxtSearchLog.Text.ToLower.Trim)) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looped through all the items and subitems searching for the text. If the text is found in a `ListViewItem`, it is added to the list and the inner `For` is exited.

```
Private Function Search(SearchText As String) As List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim FoundItems As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In lvCoffee.Items
        For Each si As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            If SearchText = si.Text Then
                FoundItems.Add(item)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return FoundItems
End Function
```